# Isekai manga/mahnwa where the main character has to train 100 hero parties to get home

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The mc gets summoned to train hero parties. Once they're trained he's sent to a new world. If he completes 100 I think he goes home, but gets the option to go to the first summoned world to see his old party.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it doesn't seem to match on the surface, I think this is [*Tsuihou sareru Tabi ni Skill wo Te ni Ireta Ore ga, 100 no Isekai de 2-shuume Musou*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/156681/Tsuihou_sareru_Tabi_ni_Skill_wo_Te_ni_Ireta_Ore_ga_100_no_Isekai_de_2-shuume_Musou).

[image: Front cover of the manga]

> A mysterious god-like entity has given Ed a crazy ordeal in which he must be expelled from a party of 100 heroes in 100 different worlds in order to return to his original world, but he finally achieves the condition and is able to return to his original world. However, as a final additional condition, he is given the chance to "see what happens to the worlds he has been banished from."... This is where he learns a shocking fact.

The "shocking fact" is that the hero party from that first world failed after he left them and the Demon King is almost done conquering the world.

After he gets kicked out of the hundredth party, he provides them with training materials.

[image: Providing training materials] <sub>Click to embiggen</sub>

Found with a search for `manga isekai "trains" "hero parties"`

Comment: thanks this is the one.... benn looking for it all day. you guys are amazing